Cannot submit chat request to VLLM Pixtral in Python using MistralAI
I have a Pixtral server running locally.
I have installed mistralai 1.2.3 on MacOS and am trying to interact with the server.
When I run
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/v1/chat/completions \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{"model": "mistralai/Pixtral-12B-2409", "messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "What is the best French cheese?"}]}'

I get back the expected response, but when I run it from Python
from mistralai import Mistral

model = "mistralai/Pixtral-12B-2409"
client = Mistral(server_url="http://localhost:8000")

chat_response = client.chat.complete(
    messages=[
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "What is the best French cheese?"
        }
    ],
    model=model,
)

print(chat_response.choices[0].message.content)


I get this error:
    raise models.SDKError(
mistralai.models.sdkerror.SDKError: API error occurred: Status 400
{"object":"error","message":"[{'type': 'extra_forbidden', 'loc': ('body', 'safe_prompt'), 'msg': 'Extra inputs are not permitted', 'input': False}]","type":"BadRequestError","param":null,"code":400}

How can I solve this problem?
